# How can I hide search results if the user types out the wrong word?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter, fetch

I am working on this little vanilla JS application, to fetch data from a JSON file and display results in HTML based on what the user is typing in. The problem is if the user types a letter that = one of the results, they can type out a wrong word and those results will keep displaying. I want the information to hide if that happens. Any suggestions?

http://starwarsinfo.surge.sh/

An example, if you type in the letter "p" all the movies will show up, but if you finish that off by typing out a word like "portal" all the movies will still show.

```
const search = document.getElementById("search");
const matchList = document.getElementById("match-list");

const searchStates = async (searchText) => {
  const res = await fetch("../data/movies.json");
  const movies = await res.json();

  let matches = movies.filter((state) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`${searchText}`, "gi");
    return state.title.match(regex) || state.episode_number.match(regex);
  });

  if (searchText.length === 0) {
    matches = [];
    matchList.innerHTML = "";
  }

  outputHtml(matches);
};

const outputHtml = (matches) => {
  if (matches.length > 0) {
    const html = matches
      .map(
        (match) => `<div class="card card-body mb-1">
            <span class="text-primary"><h4>${match.title}</h4></span><br></h4>
            <small><h6>About:</h6><br> ${match.description}</small>
        </div>`
      )
      .join("");

    matchList.innerHTML = html;
  }
};

search.addEventListener("input", () => searchStates(search.value));
```

Comment: sounds like use `new RegExp( `^${searchText}$` , 'gi')` should meet your requirements

Comment: I tried that initially, but that just made the search more difficult.

Comment: Could you show some sample data from the movies file and some search criteria that causes the error? To try to reproduce the problem you describe. In order to help you more adequately

Comment: @Mario I added a link and example up above.

 If you go to http://starwarsinfo.surge.sh/ and type in the letter "p" for example, itll show all the movies since "episode" has that letter in it. However, if you start typing out a different word, like "portal", all the movie listings will still keep showing. Im trying to get it to where it updates as the user types, but anything I try seems to not work.

Answer (score 0):

hey try by putting one extra condition

```
let matches = movies.filter(state => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`${searchText}`, 'gi');
    if( !state.title.match(regex) || !state.episode_number.match(regex) ){
     matches = [];
     matchList.innerHTML = '';
    } else return true;
});
```

Comment: hmm, that just made it not work entirely. But I will mess with it and see if there is something I can do to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the knowledge to advise on `regex` but you can achieve the desired result as follows.

Please try this example

```js
const movies = [
  {
    title: "Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace",
    episode_number: "1",
  },
  {
    title: "Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones",
    episode_number: "2",
  },
  {
    title: "Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith",
    episode_number: "3",
  },
];

const searchStates = (searchText) => {
  const matches = movies.filter((state) => {
    return (
      state.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
      state.episode_number === searchText
    );
  });

  console.log(matches);
};

searchStates("clones");
```

I would also recommend that you do not make a call to the api for each letter you type, some apis have a limited number of requests allowed in the day, and responding each time you press a key reaches the limit quickly. A better alternative is to get the data on the site load, save the results to a variable, and filter the data from there.

Comment: This was actually using a JSON file from my site files, so there was no api to eternal data. I will definitely remember that though for when I am working with that. 

I am trying to stick with the json file for this example, because I have an upcoming project with a TON of data, so moving it all individually into a js variable might be overkill.

Comment: it's true I hadn't noticed this `../data/movies.json`

Comment: no worries. Your advice is definitely good for some smaller projects though. Thanks!